# jquery datepicker with dynamic textboxes in bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker, dynamic-html

i am applying jquery datepickers on dynamic controls that follow the class jq-datepicker

just setup a jsfiddle example to demonstrate the issue datepicker with modal

[please click the link to follow demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e35vpfrn/)

when i didn't include modal the same code was working fine here is another example of working demo without modal

[please click the link to follow demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p714z0ox/3/)

Scenario : i have a chunk of code that makes ajax call and a certain div is updated when the response is returned from ajax call

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <div class="content-wrapper">

        @RenderBody()
        <div class="jq-loading-bar"></div>
        <div id="ajax-place-holder" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

below is the code snippet of code returned by ajax call made to a particular action method

```
    <div id="ajax-place-holder" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
        <div class="modal fade show" id="myModal" style="padding-right: 21px; display: block;">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <form action="/profile/updateeducation" class="jq-form" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
                            <label for="placeholder-input" class="col-sm-12 col-form-label text-center">ADD EDUCATION</label>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label" for="SelectedAcademicLevel">Academic Level</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="academic level required" id="SelectedAcademicLevel" name="SelectedAcademicLevel">
                                        <option value="">Select Academic Level</option>
                                        <option value="1">UPSR</option>
                                        <option value="2">PT3/PMR</option>
                                        <option selected="selected" value="3">SPM</option>
                                        <option value="4">Matrikulasi</option>
                                        <option value="5">STPM</option>
                                        <option value="6">STAM</option>
                                        <option value="7">SKM</option>
                                        <option value="8">Diploma</option>
                                        <option value="9">Advance Diploma</option>
                                        <option value="10">Bachelor</option>
                                        <option value="11">Master</option>
                                        <option value="12">PHD</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="SelectedAcademicLevel" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                </div>
                                <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label" for="AcademicDetailItem_courseTitle">Course Title</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="couse title should be min 10 and max 70 in length" data-val-length-max="70" data-val-length-min="10" data-val-regex="First name should contain alphabets, white spaces or characters in [-_'. (repeating one at a time)]  only." data-val-regex-pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*([ '\-_\.]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$" data-val-required="course title is required" id="AcademicDetailItem_courseTitle" name="AcademicDetailItem.courseTitle" placeholder="Enter Course Title" type="text" value="Computer Engineering">
                                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="AcademicDetailItem.courseTitle" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label" for="SelectedAcademicDiscipline">Academic Discipline</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="academic discipline required" id="SelectedAcademicDiscipline" name="SelectedAcademicDiscipline">
                                        <option value="">Select Academic Discipline</option>
                                        <option value="1">Anthropology</option>
                                        <option value="2">Applied sciences</option>
                                        <option selected="selected" value="3">Archaeology</option>
                                        <option value="4">Arts</option>
                                        <option value="5">Biology</option>
                                        <option value="6">Chemistry</option>
                                        <option value="7">Computer Science</option>
                                        <option value="8">Earth sciences</option>
                                        <option value="9">Economics</option>
                                        <option value="10">Engineering and technology</option>
                                        <option value="11">Formal sciences</option>
                                        <option value="12">History</option>
                                        <option value="13">Human geography</option>
                                        <option value="14">Humanities</option>
                                        <option value="15">Languages and literature</option>
                                        <option value="16">Law</option>
                                        <option value="17">Mathematics</option>
                                        <option value="18">Medicine and health</option>
                                        <option value="19">Natural sciences</option>
                                        <option value="20">Performing arts</option>
                                        <option value="21">Philosophy</option>
                                        <option value="22">Physics</option>
                                        <option value="23">Political science</option>
                                        <option value="24">Psychology</option>
                                        <option value="25">Social sciences</option>
                                        <option value="26">Sociology</option>
                                        <option value="27">Space sciences</option>
                                        <option value="28">Statistics</option>
                                        <option value="29">Theology</option>
                                        <option value="30">Visual arts</option>
                                        <option value="31">Other</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="SelectedAcademicDiscipline" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="placeholder-input" class="col-sm-12 col-form-label text-center">Duration from to until</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label" for="AcademicDetailItem_durationFrom">Starting Date</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <input class="form-control jq-datepicker hasDatepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Starting Date must be a date." data-val-required="Starting date is Required" id="AcademicDetailItem_durationFrom" name="AcademicDetailItem.durationFrom" placeholder="Enter Date From" type="text" value="15/11/2018">
                                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="AcademicDetailItem.durationFrom" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                </div>
                                <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label" for="AcademicDetailItem_durationUntil">Completion Date</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <input class="form-control jq-datepicker hasDatepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Completion Date must be a date." data-val-required="Completion date is Required" id="AcademicDetailItem_durationUntil" name="AcademicDetailItem.durationUntil" placeholder="Enter Date Completion" type="text" value="26/11/2018">
                                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="AcademicDetailItem.durationUntil" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!---<button type="button" id="addMore1" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add More
            </button>-->
                            <br>
                            <div class="card-body text-center">
                                <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field individualID must be a number." data-val-required="The individualID field is required." id="AcademicDetailItem_individualID" name="AcademicDetailItem.individualID" type="hidden" value="2">
                                <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field individualAcademicQualificationDetailID must be a number." data-val-required="The individualAcademicQualificationDetailID field is required." id="AcademicDetailItem_individualAcademicQualificationDetailID" name="AcademicDetailItem.individualAcademicQualificationDetailID" type="hidden" value="5">
                                <a href="/profile/edit" class="jq-loader" data-jq-action="DismissModal">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary shadow-secondary px-5" value="Cancel">Cancel</button>
                                </a>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary shadow-primary px-5 jq-loader" value=""><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Save&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

below are images of environment from where i copied the code rendered by ajax call. this code run as bootstrap Modal popup but still exist as part of div ajax-place-holder that exists on the page when first page was rendered.

[Snapshot of code Running as Modal Popup returned by ajax call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRqOS.jpg)

[Snapshot of chrome debug tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8CAc.jpg)

and here is the last part javascript code that is applying datepickers on dynamically created elements returned by ajax call.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('body').on('focus', ".jq-datepicker", function () {
          ////debugger;
          console.log('body focus jq-datepciker');
          $(this).datepicker({
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true,
              yearRange: "-100:-0",
              numberOfMonths: 1,
              dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
              showWeek: true,                
          });
          $(this).datepicker("show");            
      });
    </script>
```

this function is called everytime any input element with class jq-datepicker gets focus and code is called and executed without any erros in console.

below is snapshot of console everytime input element with same class gets focus.

[Console Log everytime input gets focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pow9o.jpg)

but i am not able to get any datepicker with my UI.

All the snapshots shown above are from google chrome.

now the problem becomes even more interesting when i run the same code on internet explorer it seems to work and datepicker displays fine on getting focus for input element, below is screen shot from internet explorer

[snapshot from internet explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTMJT.jpg)

datepicker is working fine for internet explorer but it doesn't work with either chrome or firefox i have tried everything that i am aware of with my limited knowledge but i am unable to figure out how to resolve this issue please help

Comment: I can see there are 3 red cross for Chrome browser. Might be some Javascript error which is causing script to halt and not execute. You may need to remove all JS error appearing in Console for Chrome and Firefox

Comment: script is executing fine those errors are for multiple html elements having same ID, which is not causing any issue to javascript and yet calls are made to javascript focus event everytime my textbox gets focus.

Comment: but the script is on body focus => $('body').on('focus',

Comment: i have done this as well to check $('#ajax-place-holder').on('focus', ".jq-datepicker", function () {... but the issue remains same

Comment: Here is screen shot of erros as well [link](https://imgur.com/a/bboLEtm)

Comment: I have made an edit to code please check my demos the one working with jquery and the one not working with bootstrap will help to understand the problem there on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I copied your partial and removed the modal elements, then appended the HTML via AJAX. It did not work, it broke. My code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').on('focus', ".jq-datepicker", function () {
        ////debugger;
        console.log('body focus jq-datepciker');
        $(this).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "-100:-0",
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            showWeek: true,
        });
        $(this).datepicker("show");
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Partial",
        method: "GET"
    }).done(function (data) {
        $("#mainrow").html(data);
        });
</script>
```

By removing the class hasDatepicker from

```
<input class="form-control jq-datepicker hasDatepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Completion Date must be a date." data-val-required="Completion date is Required" id="AcademicDetailItem_durationUntil" name="AcademicDetailItem.durationUntil" placeholder="Enter Date Completion" type="text" value="26/11/2018">
```

it worked. The class confuses JQuery making it think the datepicker is already open.

Comment: Oh wait, you copied that partial directly out of the page? That is why that class is in your code. If you don't have that class, your code works for me.

Comment: i have followed your tip removed hasDatepicker class from code once html is replaced with ajax call after my modal opens

[First Image without hasDatepicker class](https://imgur.com/a/SYQlL11)

then snap shot of my function getting focus for date picker

[code from visual studio for datepicker focus](https://imgur.com/a/SPZ7Am4)

then third screen shot after my input control gets focus and jquery automatically adds hasDatepicker class to my element but datepicker still won't show up

[Added hasDatepicker class by jquery (but datepicker won't show)](https://imgur.com/a/IvU5YlO)

Comment: i didn't copy that partial directly from page that partial is being generated by my code in visual studio i render partial view to string and then return that generated html as json back to ajax call on response.done(function(){});

Comment: just to add if i don't make ajax call and i run the code as server redirection call from button action or anchor herf and open modal as a view instead of partial view as a response of Action Call datepicker works fine as the page is rendered again as new page

Comment: So if the class hasDatepicker is coming from the server, that might be your problem. The $.datepicker function should add that class to the input element.

Comment: please follow my first comment to your response i have included screen shots where i removed those classes completely destroyed datepicker if it exists incase and then the hasDatepicker class is being added again by jquery when i click inside textbox to gain foucs , but datepicker doesn't show up

Comment: Oh okei... there goes that theory. In any case, one tip, you are registering a new datepicker with every click. I would rather add a class like modalDatePicker to the input and generate a datepicker once the data is loaded. Do it once of.

Comment: Last question, if you load it as a partial not via ajax, is it still in a modal? It can be that the zindex of the datepicker is lower than the zindex of the modal. And then it will never show up.

Comment: Add the following class to your page:
.ui-datepicker {
z-index:300000;
}

Comment: for first answer yes it is still in a modal with or without ajax
for 2nd answer i have included a screen shot in the question where date picker shows up and loads on top of modal also without bothering z-index i will include it again i just don't know what i have done wrong or why same exact code runs fine on internet explorer but not on chrome or firefox
here is screen shot again 
[from Internet explorer](https://imgur.com/a/ht75Cwb)

Comment: When you look at where the datepicker is appended and the z-index is inline on it as 1, the bootstrap modal does have a higer z-index. It would makes sense that the modal would be on top. But, I am out of ideas...

Comment: added the class for z-index and something different happened now once i click in textbox it completely disappeared from modal

[Screenshot after clicking in textbox to get focus](https://imgur.com/a/gzrcnTa)

Comment: a bundle of thanks for your help still to give your precious time, unfortunately i am out of ideas as well, i just have one solution left if it didn't work i might change it to bootstrap datepicker instead of jquery datepicker